# Beethoven Op. 22 No.1 Measures 16-20

Tags: piano, technique

Does anyone have any excercises for voicing in this section other than rhythms and over accenting? [image]

Comment: I apologize, this is the passage I was mentioning, and I am just curious if there's any other way to practice voicing rather than overemphasizing or doing rhythms.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not a pianist, but can you elaborate what the challenge is or the goal? Is this about effectively bringing out the melody over the supporting voices?

Comment: I would practice the right hand at a slower tempo, playing the top-line sixteenth notes almost as if they were eighth notes and striving for something approaching a legato. This will help avoid choppiness with the alternating thirds that works against hearing a singing melodic line. That will sound better than any type of punchy accent.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that

Comment: Yes, you've gotta have a strong pinky-finger for this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend practicing each pair of sixteenth notes as a block chord. When this can be done with the proper voicing, it will be easier to maintain that voicing when playing as written.

Here's a notated example of what I mean:

[image: Passage re-notated with eighth-note block chords]

Another possibility that could be explored is to play the inner voice entirely with the left hand, leaving the right hand to play the melody only.

[image: Passage re-notated to give all harmony parts to left hand]

Comment: Love those options! Thank you for your time to actually notate it!